# Need to set a Fall Back Locale in Zendframework

Tags: php, zend-framework

I'm using zend for a new project. But I need to set a default fall back (fallbacklocale) message. By default, Zend returns the same string that was passed by parameter.

For example, I passed (View):

```
$this->translate("blocks_title");
```

Zend returns (Uf the key is not in my translation file):

```
blocks_title
```

What I need:

```
"Error: Missing translation key"
```

Any tips? Thank you so much!

Comment: yes, you should use a different way to translate, the gettext translation will use the current key as a translation if does not find any other, so the keys should be things like $this->translate("My title in main website language");

Comment: How ever the program POEditor will find all the empty keys, then you could run a script on the files that will replace "" with "Error: Missing translation key" but I don't see it really maintainable.